# Login to Linux automatically without input username and password

Tags: linux, login, autologin

I'm working with Linux (Fedora) without a GUI (I've disabled it).  In the system, there is one user (`tarik`).  I would like to log in automatically without typing the username and password. I have already deleted the password using the command:

```bash
passwd -d tarik
```

However, I don't know how to automatically log in to the user without typing the username.

Thanks

Comment: You always have more users in a linux system. `cat /etc/passwd` gives you an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Fedora, I'll presume you use *systemd* as init system and that the console you want to log from is a virtual console (tty[N]), that is to say not a serial console. Additionally assuming that *agetty* is running at startup. :

What you need is to override the default parameters given to agetty. You will need to define some service editing `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf` for example and add the following lines :

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -f -- \\u' --noclear --autologin tarik %I $TERM
```

Comment: you can see login sceen [link](https://github.com/TarikVUT/Store-/blob/main/images/login.png)

Comment: @TarikAlkanan : Sorry but I just get an http 404 when clicking on your link.

Comment: Oo,Sorry ,there is it  [image](https://github.com/TarikVUT/Store-/blob/main/images/login.png)